# not running on AppKit (main) thread issue when navigating to another xib

Tags: swift, macos, swift4, xib, safari-extension

The use case of my application is there is a login ui which is handled in `SafariExtensionViewController.xib` and when the user hits the login button another UI has to be shown and that is `ExtensionStepsViewController.xib`. I used following for navigating to another screen

```
self.presentViewControllerAsSheet(ExtensionStepsViewController())
```

However, i am getting following issue

> - Assertion failure in void assertRunningOnAppKitThread(void)(), 2018-09-05 15:02:30.318742+0545 extension[13150:1422110]
>     [General] not running on AppKit (main) thread

Here is my code

SafariExtensionViewController.swift

```
import SafariServices

class SafariExtensionViewController: SFSafariExtensionViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var passwordMessage: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailMessage: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var message: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var email: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: NSSecureTextField!
    static let shared = SafariExtensionViewController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        message.stringValue = ""
        emailMessage.stringValue = ""
        passwordMessage.stringValue = ""
    }


    @IBAction func userLogin(_ sender: Any) {
        let providedEmailAddress = email.stringValue
        let providedPassword = password.stringValue
        let isEmailAddressValid = isValidEmailAddress(emailAddressString: providedEmailAddress)
        self.message.stringValue = ""
        emailMessage.stringValue = ""
        passwordMessage.stringValue = ""
        if isEmailAddressValid && providedPassword.count > 0 {
            let session = URLSession.shared
            var request = URLRequest(url: URI!)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            do {
                request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

                guard error == nil else {
                    return
                }

                guard let data = data else {
                    return
                }

                do {
                    //create json object from data
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                            if (httpResponse.statusCode >= 200 && httpResponse.statusCode < 300) {
                                print("#########LOGIN########################")
                                self.message.stringValue = "Login Successful"
                                self.message.textColor = NSColor.green

                                UserDefaults.standard.set(providedEmailAddress, forKey: "email")
                                self.presentViewControllerAsSheet(ExtensionStepsViewController()) // error is thrown after this action
                            } else {
                                self.message.stringValue = "Invalid Credentials"
                                self.message.textColor = NSColor.red
                            }
                        }
                        // handle json...
                    }
                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        } else {
            emailMessage.textColor = NSColor.red
            emailMessage.stringValue = "Invalid Email"
        }
    }

  }
```

ExtensionStepsViewController.swift

```
import SafariServices

class ExtensionStepsViewController: SFSafariExtensionViewController {

//    static let shared = SafariExtensionViewController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Hello") // this is also printed 
        // Do view setup here.
    }

}
```

when login is successful and then this statement gets executed `self.presentViewControllerAsSheet(ExtensionStepsViewController())` the `print("hello")` gets printed in the debug section and i get the listed issue.

Answer (score 1):

All updates to UI must be done from the main thread. It seems that the `completionHandler` is not called on the main thread, which causes this assertion to fail.

You need to perform your presenting on the main queue. You can do this by scheduling a block as follows:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  // This will  now run on the main queue.
  self.presentViewControllerAsSheet(ExtensionStepsViewController())
}
```

Comment: i dont this one is working or not but the issue is not now there. It gets navigated but the window gets closed within a second.

Comment: That is because no one holds a strong reference to the object - it's getting deallocated